# How to display object variable value in label

Tags: javascript, c#, json

I have a method which has object return type in a class library, I am using javascript Deserializer and returning the object data. And created the DLL of this class and calling this class in another project. I am getting the data in that class but confuse how to display the object type data in label controls.

This is the class library method:

```
public class HttpRequestResponse
{
    private WebRequest request;    
         public object Fetchresult()
    {          
        request = WebRequest.Create("URL");               
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();                 Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
            dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        object obj = js.Deserialize<dynamic>(responseFromServer);
        return obj;               

    }
}
```

This is the calling class:

```
HttpRequestResponse cls = new HttpRequestResponse();
object obj= cls.Fetchresult();
Label3.Text = obj["name"];
```

I am getting the value in `obj` but how to display this value in label control.
Thanks

Comment: Where do you set `responseFromServer`?

Comment: In the calling class you've declared `obj` as an `object` instead of `dynamic` so you can't access the properties.

Comment: Can you add the class which belongs to your response or just add the content of `obj`?

Comment: Thanks @stuartd that worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution

```
dynamic obj = cls.Fetchresult(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you can like this. So, you always have an object of type you wanted.

```
public class HttpRequestResponse
{
    private WebRequest request;
    public T Fetchresult<T>()
    {
        request = WebRequest.Create("URL");
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
        var dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var obj = js.Deserialize<T>(responseFromServer);
        return obj;

    }
}
```

Can use this like:

```
List<int> list = HttpRequestResponse.Fetchresult<List<int>>();
```

Or

```
ClassName obj = HttpRequestResponse.Fetchresult<ClassName>();
```